# TextView where drawableTop doesn't scale

Tags: android, xml, textview, drawable, stretch

I have a TextView-"button" that has drawableTop attribute set to a nice icon.
However, when I changed to a smaller screen that icon remains the same size, but is cropped. I do not want this, I want the drawableTop-icon to shrink when the original icon no longer fits. Is it possible to do this (preferably in xml)?

Comment: Use the `drawable-*dpi` buckets. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I'd like to have something universal, so no different images. I'd like it to stretch the image it has. That way it'll always work.

Comment: The universal way is what I told you. OR switch to using SVG files (which, being VECTORS, are SCALABLE by definition). You'd need to use a library, though.

Comment: The method suggested by @Frank is the standard way

Comment: But I mean, If I have an imagebutton I can have any image stretched. I wonder if I can also have this stretch-behaviour for drawableTop on TextView (or some other view).

Comment: No, compound drawables don't scale. Because the aren't seen as a **background**, but as a **src**. MAybe, you can MANUALLY rescale the drawable and then reassign it programmatically (by using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`).

Comment: OK. Thx for answer! The things is that each button (and I have many) consists of four different images (states), which would amount to a massive amount of images for different screen sizes, and that is something i would like to avoid.

Comment: That's really a perfect job for SVG files. `1 File = Every Size` you need to scale it to, *without quality loss*.

Comment: But the strange thing is that if I make the icon smaller in pixels, it still gets scaled up to the same size (though ugly)! Some stretching is going on somewhere but I can't find the attribute...